# Go through each image named with same class but assigning them different widths

Tags: jquery

I have the following code which goes through each image that has the class .image-resize and gives them a newWidth depending on the screen size. However I would like to give each image different newWidth, for example I want the images to be given these values:

1st image) `newWidth = 'wid=860&crop=0,0,860,650';`

2nd image) `newWidth = 'wid=760&crop=0,0,760,650';`

3rd image) `newWidth = 'wid=560&crop=0,0,560,650';`

4th image) `newWidth = 'wid=460&crop=0,0,460,650';`

as you see each one has slightly different parameters, how could I achieve that?

HTML

```
  <img class="image-resize" src="http://images.domain.com/is/image/domain/style7?wid=960&crop=0,0,960,650">
    <img class="image-resize" src="http://images.domain.com/is/image/domain/style7?wid=960&crop=0,0,960,650">
    <img class="image-resize" src="http://images.domain.com/is/image/domain/style7?wid=960&crop=0,0,960,650">
    <img class="image-resize" src="http://images.domain.com/is/image/domain/style7?wid=960&crop=0,0,960,650">
```

JQUERY

```
$('.image-resize').each(function() {
    var element = $(this),
        src = $(this).attr('src'),
        regx = /(wid.*)$/g,
        currentWidth,
        newWidth,
        newCrop,
        newSrc,
        parameters;

   if ($(window).width() > 623) { 
     /* Large Displays ----------- */
     //Return large image if screen size is over 768px
     currentWidth = src.match(regx);
     newWidth = 'wid=960&crop=0,0,960,650';
     newSrc = src.replace(currentWidth, newWidth);


   }   else if ($(window).width() <= 623) {
     /* Smartphones ----------- */
     currentWidth = src.match(regx);
     newWidth = 'wid=640&crop=360,0,600,400';
     newSrc = src.replace(currentWidth, newWidth);
   }

   element.attr('src', newSrc);
});
```

Comment: Well you would place the values somewhere where your script could read them from … either as a config array of some sort, or perhaps by using custom `data-` attributes on the image elements …

Answer (score 0):

According to what logic the image sized differ? or do you have a list of images and all have their own sizes given manually?

And I think you are using server-side img resizing code. And with this approach your images will be rendered first with given variables and then rerendered with the new values calculated according to the window width.

This is waste of server resources.

You can create images on javascript / jquery and append them to the places on screen with the calculated / recieved values. This way you will keep all the logic in one place and saved server from re-creating the images.